# use JNI and java servlet or CGI and C language?

Tags: java, c, servlets, web, cgi

I've to develop web application, I must use a C function server side, and I don t know if it is better use java servlet with JNI framework or CGI with C language.
I must upload zip file, client side, and use this file with a specific C function.
what is the better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it all depends.  If this is a function that you have to use for a long time and you've got a Java environment already then it will be worth wrapping it in JNI.  But if this is a single project then I'd say that if you've already got to use a C function you're just going to complicate your life by putting JNI on top of it.

CGI is very simple to handle, even in C.  JNI can be challenging and would be more so in a web environment.

Comment: Thanks man for your answer. 
This project has now started and it s based to use a C function server side. you say it is better to use CGI with C?

Comment: you opinion is important for me

Comment: It depends on the setup.  CGI allows you to separate the function from the web server.  An alternative is to write an Apache module (assuming you're using Apache) but then if you need to upgrade the server you're tightly coupled to the server version.  A separate CGI script allows easier maintenance.  The downside is that you'll need to handle the CGI protocol in the C program but there are examples (https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/cgic.html) that show you how to do that pretty easily.

Comment: thanks, I think will use CGI with C after your answer

Comment: sure man.
can I ask you another thing?
If I must upload file from web form to web server, with CGI and C, how should I do?
This is my first time that work with CGI witch C language.

Comment: I found http://libccgi.sourceforge.net/doc.html and http://www.qdecoder.org/ that have examples of getting a file from a C CGI program.  The second one seems to be better maintained but I've not actually used either one.